# Rep league should have search by user name/id

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, reputation-leagues

Users may want to see the ranking of those who don't appear on the first page or two without having to repeatedly click on the next page button. They should be able to search by user name or ID (their own or others').

Comment: I like the title better than the question.  Why limit it to "me"?  What if I want to know someone else's rank? @Jeff's answer resolves your question, but not the title.

Comment: @rchern: My intention was not that it be limited to "me", hence the word "search" in both the title and the question. However, I see that it can be clarified. See my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global auth is used on stackexchange.com now, so we're planning to highlight "you" at the top of the list, if you have > 200 rep on the target site.

Comment: What about a search feature?

Comment: See my clarification.